# Call Ajax Get function inside mRender Datatable

Tags: ajax, json, datatables

I am looking to call an ajax function inside the Datatables mRender function that will use an id from the present ajax source to get data from a different ajax source.

To put this into perspective, I have:

A listing of requisitions from different clients in one Datatable.

In this listing I have a client id. I want to get the client Name to be shown on the table instead of the client Id. However the Client Name and other client details are in the clients table hence these details are not in the requisitions json data. But I have the Client Id.

How do I use this to get client name inside the mrender function? E.g

```
{"sTitle":"Client","mData":null,
    "mRender":function(data){
    //ajax function     
   }
},
```

Thank you in advance,
Regards.

Comment: i am also looking for doing this , have you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is how you are supposed to deal with your data. However I also use an AJAX data source in my mRender function as stated below.

```
    $(document).ready(function(e){
       $('.products').dataTable({
           "bProcessing": true,
           "sAjaxSource":  window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + '/product/getAll',
           "aoColumns": [
               { "sTitle": "Pid", "bVisible" : false},
               { "sTitle": "Pname" },
               { "sTitle": "Pprice" },
               {   "sTitle": "Pgroups",
                   "mRender" : function( data, type, full ){
                        console.log( data, type, full );
                        console.log(category.getAll());
                       return 'test';
                   }
               }
            ]
        });
    });
```

De category object is initialized in a selfinvoking function. I used this to prevent the function from loading the data remotely each time the function is called.
It looks like this:

```
    (function(){
        if(typeof category === 'undefined'){
            category = {};
        }
        category.getAll = function(){
            if(typeof category.all === 'undefined'){
                $.ajax({
                    'type' : 'POST',
                    'async': false,
                    'url' : window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/category/getAll",
                    'success' : function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        category.all = data;
                    },
                    'error': function(a,b,c){
                        console.log("You shall not pass!",a,b,c);
                        alert('stop');
                    }
                });
            }
            return category.all;
        }
    })();
```